# python ldap search with flask-kerberos credentials

Tags: python, flask, ldap, kerberos

Is there any way to use the authenticated user or the server keytab in a python3/flask-kerberos application to query ldap?

I am using flask-kerberos connecting to active directory and is authenticating correctly.  I need to add authorization now based on the AD group and understand ldap is typically the best practice. 
I am able to query successfully via ldap3, but I do not want to hardcode ldap bind credentials in my code.
The sasl/kerberos bind option for ldap3 looks like it needs an OS level credential-cache, but I would like to do this completely within the application.
Looking for any suggestions/alternatives to do this.

Comment: Can u please provide me the code , i am looking for this, but not getting anywhere.also some references from where to look for !!

Comment: @AkshayIndalkar You are looking for the code to use kerberos or ldap or both?

Comment: i am looking for both. I am using flask, now i want to implement kerberos with ldap

Comment: Caveat: I'm a sysadmin, not a programmer, so this may be horrible security/practice. 
But as the sysadmin mantra states "It works, so..."  
This is combining authentication with authorization. Also, requires a service account to query LDAP.
I have other applications that also require this, so it didn't seem untoward.
Also, I am hardcoding various values (username/passwords/servernames/etc) in this example code, 
but in practice, I am importing them using the python configparser.

https://pastebin.com/2DNSuY8D
#code was too long for stack overflow

Comment: thanks for your code. I had some queries, and it will help me :(1).How to create the keytab file.?(I have created using Active Directory server). (2.)Is there any kerberos environment we require? or just need to install flask-kerberos and ldap3.and specify the keytab file? (3.) In line 48 of your code , the user u specified 'ldapQueryServiceAccount' is an user of ldap?

Comment: You need a sysadmin to add a kerberos environment to your unix host and join it to  active directory.  This process creates the keytab file with the required info to connect to the domain.  Our company uses Centrify for this. If you have a keytab file for a server that is joined into AD, then that is all you need. The keys in the keytab expire so need to be refreshed via the kerberos environment.
the ldapservice account is just a AD service account that has access to query AD. This account is separate from any account being authenticated. It is only used to perform the query.

Comment: how to configure the krb5.conf  file. Can u show me the file.? Also how can i get the Kerberos credentials cache. FILE:/tmp/krb5cc

Comment: The conf file is a part of the OS Kerberos config. That is a whole separate topic unrelated to python that needs a Unix admin (my file is 500 lines auto configured by centrify) the krb5cc is a client cache that is not needed for python server applications doing authentication in this way. You need a server keytab , not a client cache. I can’t share my config file as it has mostly specific information about my corporate domain.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you are mixing up authentication and authorization, but with no useful information provided regarding your code or setup its hard to help.

Take a look at something like this, and use ldap as impersonation to authenticate your users using their own credentials.

Comment: I guess I'm looking for some higher-level best practice advice.  If you are authenticating with flask-kerberos, what is the typical way to do group-based authorization.  Assuming it is ldap, then what credentials are typically used to query ldap.  I'd like to use the credentials that were used in the authentication process, but have no idea on how to do that in this kerberos-type authentication

Comment: In an enterprise environment I would usually tackle it this way, where you offload the authenticate to something like apache and have it do the authentication, and have your app focus exclusively on the authorization of your api.

https://www.roguelynn.com/words/apache-kerberos-for-django/